# Swing: Any line I draw by mouse drag only shows up the next time I drag the mouse

Tags: java, swing, repaint, line-drawing

I'm still learning the basics of Java, so sorry if this question is basic. What I've tried to do is to store the points and lines into `ArrayLists` and then have the `paintComponent()` method go through them and draw them each time its called. Since I'm using the same `ArrayList` for my points, I clear it every time the mouse is pressed, so the new line won't connect with the previous one.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;

   private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
   private ArrayList<Curves> curvedLines = new ArrayList<Curves>();

    public MyPanel() {

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                points.clear();
                points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                ArrayList<Point> newPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
                for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                    newPoints.add(points.get(i));
                }
                curvedLines.add(new Curves(newPoints));
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);


            for (int c = 0; c < points.size() - 1; c++) {
                x = (int) points.get(c).getX();
                y = (int) points.get(c).getY();
                x2 = (int) points.get(c + 1).getX();
                y2 = (int) points.get(c + 1).getY();
                g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
            }


            for (int t = 0; t < curvedLines.size(); t++) {
                ArrayList<Point> iterator = curvedLines.get(t).points;
                for (int c = 0; c < iterator.size() - 1; c++) {
                    x = (int) iterator.get(c).getX();
                    y = (int) iterator.get(c).getY();
                    x2 = (int) iterator.get(c + 1).getX();
                    y2 = (int) iterator.get(c + 1).getY();
                    g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
                }
            }

    }


        class Curves {
            private ArrayList<Point> points;

            public Curves(ArrayList<Point> points) {
                this.points = new ArrayList<Point>();
                this.points = points;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that while I drag the mouse, no line is drawn, but its points are still being stored since the line appears when I drag the mouse again. What is causing this apparent delay?

Comment: You were given an answer yesterday when you asked a similar question. How is your code different than the code you were given? The point is you should compare your code to the working code to find the difference. You need to learn to debug your own code. I would guess the answer is you don't need the if/else statement in the painting code.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to add this question to my previous one without it getting messy, so I figured I would post it as its own question. I added the if/else statement because the `paintComponenet` wouldn't draw anything until I had an element in my `curvedLines` ArrayList, so my first line would not get drawn. I looked at code samples before, but I couldn't readily see why my code shouldn't also work. Maybe I just don't understand the logic/structure behind Swing components very well.

Comment: You were not asked to add this question to your previous one. You should only have one question per thread. Your question was answered so you should be "accepting" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I wanted to add this question because I was simply still confused. I already spent a few hours trying to figure things out. As for the if/else statement, I was having the issue before I added it. As I mentioned above, the if/else statement was to address another issue, which it successfully did. If I had to guess, it may be the `for` statement, which I had prior to containing it within the if/else. I didn't know about the checkmark or needing to add the entire code. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `As for the if/else statement...` - get rid of it and try your code again as I suggested in my answer. It worked fine for me when I tested it. If it doesn't work then post your `SSCCE` (without the if/else statement) that demonstrates the problem because the code you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: The posted code still contains the if/else statement.

Comment: You never paint the values which are in the `points` list

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought that's what my `for` loop did?

Comment: @Mystic See Camckr's answer, it's the `if-else` statement which is screwing with you

Comment: @MadProgrammer I already tried deleting the `if-else` and leaving the `for` loop that's within the `else` brackets, and the problem persists.

Comment: @Mystic, Nobody has ever said the problem is with the for loop so why do you keep mentioning it. The code you posted still has the if/else statement. Two of the top Swing experts are telling you that it works if your remove the if/else statement. You have been asked to post your code without the if/else statement. Why have you not done this??? Its possible there is a version/platform issue, or you simply did not remove the if/else statement correctly. We can't tell if you don't post your code showing the change you have made.

Comment: @Mystic Also add `repaint` to the end of `mosueReleased` so it repaints the updated curve's, I took you code, remove the `if-else` statement and added `repaint` to `mouseReleased` and it works just fine. Camickr's answer is correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer, The repaint() is not needed in the mouseReleased() method for reasons I explained in Resits answer. It doesn't hurt but it is NOT needed because all the Points have been painted in the mouseDragged() method. Or are you saying this is a Windows/Mac difference?

Comment: @camickr No, I'm just over cautious about painting the current known state, since the OP changed the state, I just updated the UI, as you say, it's not needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't realize I was expected to update my code on here. I had simply removed it in my IDE, and nothing changed. I'll edit the code above. This is my first time posting a question on stackexchange, so I apologize for not being fully up to speed on how to work through code problems on here.

Comment: @Mystic. No you removed a block of code. I said you need to execute the two blocks of code every time. You still need the 2 for loops to paint the points and curves separately. Just remove the if statement, the else statement and the braces. Leave the code contained inside the if/else blocks. This is why you repost your code changes. We can't see what you have done.

Comment: @camickr  Oh. I guess I had thought the `for` loop I left did the two jobs you had referred to earlier. Alright I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `I didn't realize I was expected to update my code on here` - well normally you don't update your code because you ask a question, read the answer, implement the suggestion, hopefully it works and then you accept the answer so everybody knows the problem has been solved. In this case two you were told what the problem was, and implemented it incorrectly. We needed to see if your implementation was what was suggested.

Comment: @camickr I get it now. I'm sure my future questions will be smoother. I've been misunderstanding quite a bit on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my original comment you were asked to compare the working code given in the last question to the code you posted here to see what the difference is.

The difference is that you added the if/else statement in the paintComponent() method.

> I added the if/else statement because the paintComponenet wouldn't draw anything

That doesn't make any sense. When you add an if/else statement it means that only one type of painting can be done, either paint the curves or paint the points but you can never do both.

You always want to do both:

1. paint the points as they are added in the mouseDragged() event
2. paint all the old points that have been added to your curves.

So get rid of the if/else statement.

Also, in the future when you post code post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) se we can execute the code. The code posted here doesn't have a main() method or a JFrame so it can't be compiled and tested.

Comment: I had the issue before I included the if/else statement. At first I had only the `for` loop you see above, where it iterates through the `curvedLines` list, retrieving each element(line), and then drawing a line between every point comprising that element. But I noticed that my `curvedLines` list starts out empty, so the `for` loop would not run the first time I dragged my mouse. So I put the `if/else` statement so that it would run the `for` loop both before `curvedLines` had any elements and afterwards.

Comment: @Mystic, you are making it extremely difficult to help you. The issue you had before is irrelevant. All that is relevant is the code you post in the forum for us to look at. That is all we can base our suggestion on. How many times have I suggested the problem is the if/else statement??? Did you remove the if/else statement from the code you just posted. If I can take the time to answer your question don't you think you can take the time to try my suggestion???

Comment: I apologize, I hadn't realized you wanted me to repost my code onto here. I took it off and tried it on my own and nothing changed. I'll post it here though.

Comment: @Mystic. No you removed a block of code. I said you need to execute the two blocks of code every time. You still need the 2 for loops to paint the points and curves separately. Just remove the if statement, the else statement and the braces. Leave the code contained inside the if/else blocks. This is why you repost your code changes. We can't see what you have done.

Comment: @camikr Looks like it works. Sorry for all the miscommunication. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Based on camickr's recommendations, it works just fine for me

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SwingPaintDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingPaintDemo2();
    }

    public SwingPaintDemo2() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int x2;
        private int y2;

        private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        private ArrayList<Curves> curvedLines = new ArrayList<Curves>();

        public MyPanel() {

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    points.clear();
                    points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    ArrayList<Point> newPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                        newPoints.add(points.get(i));
                    }
                    curvedLines.add(new Curves(newPoints));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            for (int c = 0; c < points.size() - 1; c++) {
                x = (int) points.get(c).getX();
                y = (int) points.get(c).getY();
                x2 = (int) points.get(c + 1).getX();
                y2 = (int) points.get(c + 1).getY();
                g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
            }
            for (int t = 0; t < curvedLines.size(); t++) {
                ArrayList<Point> iterator = curvedLines.get(t).points;
                for (int c = 0; c < iterator.size() - 1; c++) {
                    x = (int) iterator.get(c).getX();
                    y = (int) iterator.get(c).getY();
                    x2 = (int) iterator.get(c + 1).getX();
                    y2 = (int) iterator.get(c + 1).getY();
                    g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
                }
            }
        }

        class Curves {

            private ArrayList<Point> points;

            public Curves(ArrayList<Point> points) {
                this.points = new ArrayList<Point>();
                this.points = points;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem for me was I didn't understand that I  needed both `for` loop blocks. I had only kept the second block.

Comment: I have quick question about your addition of `EventQueue`, `UIManager`, `run`, etc. I'm not familiar with any of that. What purpose do they serve? Does that section of code fall under a certain category in oracle doc where I could look into it?

Comment: UIManager sets the look and feel to the "system" look and feel because I hate Metal. EventQueue.invokeLater ensures all my ui code is started within the context of the EDT, which overcomes some issues on done systems